# Deficiency indices and dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A:D(A)\subset H \rightarrow H$ a linear operator. In what sense are the deficiency indices

$$\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ran}(A+ z) )\text{ }(z\in \mathbb{C})$$

defined?

I mean how to make sense of the dimension here?

Is it the number of basis vectors where the basis is defined as a Schauder basis of orthonormal vectors?

My motivation to aks this:

Two Hilbert spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same Hilbert dimension. Hilbert dimension is defined in terms of a Schauder basis of orthonormal vectors. Using this fact one can show that a symmetric and closed operator has a selfadjoint extention iff

$$\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ran}(A+i)^\perp)=\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ran}(A-i)^\perp)$$

I doubt that this would hold when we use a different notion for the dimension.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance; is there something wrong with the usual notion of dimension? In any case the answer is either finite or $\infty$, and in the finite case there is no need to bother with Schauder bases.

Comment: Yes there is something wrong with it. Because it has consequences for othere things. For instance two Hilbert spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same Hilbert dimension. Hilbert dimension is defined in terms of a Schauder basis of orthonormal vectors. Using this fact one can show that a symmetric and closed operator has a selfadjoint extention iff $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ran}(A+i)^\perp)=\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ran}(A-i)^\perp)$. I doubt that this would hold when we use a different notion for the dimension.

Comment: According to a functional analysis book (Werner Funktionalanalysis p 376, unfortunatly in german) that i own, the dimension meant here is the Hilbert space dimension.

Comment: @jd27 nice! Can you tell me the name of the book?

Comment: @MackeyTopology The same definition is also given in Rudin Functional Analysis on page 360 (section 13.20)

Comment: @jd27 Thank you I will look that up